# How to partition the data while reading a table in spark-jdbc if there are multiple columns given in a primary key constraint?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to load an RDBMS table from postgres into a Hive table on postgres. To do that I wrote the following line to pull the data:

```
val inputDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl).option("dbtable", s"(${query}) as inpData").option("user", devUserName).option("password", devPassword).option("partitionColumn","empID").
option("lowerBound", 14345745528L).option("upperBound", 1152921477111580662L).option("numPartitions",100).load()
```

spark-submit:

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-submit --conf spark.ui.port=4090 --driver-class-path /home/repuser/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar  --jars /home/repuser/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar --num-executors 120 --executor-cores 15 --executor-memory 50G --driver-memory 30G --driver-cores 4 --class com.partition.source.datacount counter.11-0.1.jar --master=yarn --deploy-mode=cluster --keytab /home/repuser/repuser.keytab --principal repuser@DEV.COM --files /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml,testconnection.properties --name Counter --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/repuser/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar
```

The table I am trying to read has a column: orderID which is a primary key and has unique values. The values lower bound: min value of orderID and upper bound: max value are given along with the column name: orderID in the value: oprion("partitionColumn", "orderID") and the code runs well picking up all the data from GreenPlum and inserting the same data into Hive.

But there are some tables with two columns as primary keys. For example I have a table `userLocation` that has two columns: `referenceID & headerID` as its primary key. Is there a way to use multiple column names in `.option("partitionColumn", columnName)`.

I understand that the option `partitionColumn` need not be a primary key column.
If there isn't a single column with unique values how, could anyone let me know how can I partition the data while reading the table ?

Comment: You could just use the major part of the primary key as long as it is numeric.

Comment: I'd try increasing available memory or decreasing the number of partitions first (let's say to 800 - 1600). Try to better approximate the distribution will help you only if it is not uniform - do you have any reason to suspect that? Also, I am not aware of any resources that would describe that - just a common sense.

Comment: @thebluephantom The columns: referenceID & headerID are of numeric datatypes. Hence the reason I am using those.

Comment: @user6910411Earlier there was skew problem in the code. I was giving "source_system_name" as "partitionColumn", lower & upper bounds as 1 and 50000 which were totally wrong. Hence all the data was going into a single partition therefore making the distribution among the partitions uneven and causing a skew issue. After understanding the concept correctly, I got it right for the table I gave in the line: inputDF which had 560mb of data. But when I applied the same on a huge table, this time with proper keyColumn & bounds, I see this GCOverhead issue popping up again.

Comment: @user6910411 Could you tell me how can I implement the percentile logic ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE